# How to CORRECTLY access LIVE camera data on Android? How does Skype do it?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-camera, skype

I have seen many similar questions but no one gives a 100% answer:

1. Camera.PreviewCallback does not guarantee needed framerate on all devices
2. MediaRecorder might buffer audio/video on some devices (before it is written to the file / local socket)
3. Native C/C++ API is not public and everyone strongly discourages from using it.

How does Skype do it? What's the correct way to access live video frames on Android?

Answer (score 2):

On Android versions before 3.0, preview callbacks are the only option; please make sure you use the [setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29) method, which is far more efficient.

On Honeycomb or later, you can also use a GPU path through [setPreviewTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29). This will get the preview stream straight into a GPU texture, which is more appropriate for some applications.

You won't gain any huge performance gains from trying to use the internal C/C++ API, and it is guaranteed to change in future releases, so I don't recommend using it.

Make sure you're setting the preview frame rate as high as possible, from the list of supported frame rates.

If you require a high, stable frame rate, you can also experiment with setting the [recording hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRecordingHint%28boolean%29) to true on newer devices.

Unfortunately, neither of those methods is guaranteed to provide a stable output frame rate, which is very dependent on the scene conditions and the particulars of a device's auto-exposure algorithm. This is something we hope will be improved in the future.

However, I would be very surprised if one of the two options above isn't what Skype et al use.

Comment: I saw many people using MediaRecorder / local socket approach, that saves you from separately capturing and synchronizing audio. But comes at a cost of buffering danger & having to "open up" the resulting file ...

what's your opinion on that?

Comment: It's a lot of overhead (running the device's video encoder and decoder all the time). And in general, there's no guarantee about the latency of that route (certainly going to be several frames at the minimum). However, I've never looked into the approach, so I can't speak authoritatively about it